# How did '-ikos' evolve into '-ic'?

Tags: etymology, greek

> [-ics](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ics&allowed_in_frame=0) [<--]
>       in the names of sciences or disciplines (acoustics, aerobics, economics, etc.) it represents a 16c. revival of the classical custom of using the neuter plural of adjectives with -ikos (see [-ic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ic&allowed_in_frame=0)) to mean "matters relevant to" and also as the titles of treatises about them. **Subject matters that acquired their names in English before c. 1500, however, tend to remain in singular** (such as arithmetic, logic).

What is a right way of interpreting the semantic jump from the original plural ***-ikos*** to the aberrant singular **-ic** (before the correct reversion to **-ics**, in the 16 century, per above)?
Please expose and explain all (hidden and missing) semantic drifts and links.

Comment: The citation tells you expressly that "it represents a 16c. revival of the classical custom of using the neuter **plural** of adjectives with -ikos ... to mean "matters relevant to".

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. Sorry about the confusion; I corrected the temporal order.

Comment: But the older use, *the mathematic* (or *-ick* or *-ique*) is in no way 'aberrant': just as in Greek and Latin, it's merely a substantive use of what in other contexts is an adjective -- and English adjectives do not inflect.

Comment: Evidently there is now a suffix -s meaning "subject/study of __", since I now hear "maths" where once (in my youth) "math" would have been used as short for "mathematics".

Comment: @GregLee This appears to derive from the abbreviation *maths.*, current throughout the 19th century in contexts like school calendars and advertisements for teachers, and to have entered English school slang around the beginning of the 20th century. *Jones II. looked like he did when Newman, the maths. master, found he'd got four answers the same as mine, and mine were all wrong.* -Windsor Magazine, 1904.

Comment: "Maths" (and not "math") has always been the word in British English.

Comment: -os is an ending for the word, not a part of the root. I'm a bit confused by your question

Answer (score 3):

Ancient Greek used both the feminine singular and the neuter plural to refer to subjects and fields through an -*ikos* adjective. The feminine singular was considered to imply *technē* "art"; the neuter plural implied "things relevant to". Thus, per [LSJ](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/contextualize.pl?p.45.LSJ.122460), Aristotle referred to mathematics as both *hē Mathematikē* (fem.sg) and as *ta Mathematika* (neut.pl)

In Latin, the feminine singular was the form that prevailed (as far as I know): [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mathematica) gives only the singular mathematica, which implied *ars* "art" just as the singular Greek implied *technē*.

It thus follows that mediaeval languages, which had contact with Latin and not Greek, would use singular forms: *arsmetick* = arithmetic; while the 16th century revival, which was much more of Greek than of Latin learning, served to reintroduce the Greek plural form, and remodel field names in English in the plural: Mathematics, Physics. That remodelling has not taken place in other languages, like French and German, which have kept their -ic/-ik/-ique field names in the singular.